# Optimise the selection of an array in a loop

Tags: java, android

How can I change the array name in every loop ?

Here the simplified version of my code :

```
if (POSITION1 == 1) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
    R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Électron_P));
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

if (POSITION1 == 2) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
    R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Monstre_P));
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

if (POSITION1 == 3) {
   ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
   R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Neutron_P));
   listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I would like to make it work in a single loop, but I don't understand what needs to replace the array's name

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { 
    if (POSITION1 == i) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
        R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.??????));
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated but you should use a switch case btw

Comment: Create an array, map indexes to their values: `values[1] = R.array.Electron_P`. You can then access the value you need via `getStringArray(values[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the loop part of your question but you could use a dictionary to store valid values for `POSITION1`

```
int[] options= new int[] {
    R.array.Électron_P,
    R.array.Monstre_P,
    R.array.Neutron_P
};

int resId = options[POSITION1 - 1];
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
            R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
            getResources().getStringArray(resId));
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Could simply use an `int` array for this. Java doesn't support primitive generics, which means the type argument would need to be `Integer`, resulting in unboxing each time the value is needed.

Comment: @VinceEmigh: took your advice, long time now working with Java. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can not use loops,try this:

```
    HashMap positions = new LinkedHashMap();

    positions.put(1,R.array.Électron_P);
    positions.put(2,R.array.Monstre_P);
    positions.put(3,R.array.Neutron_P);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
            R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
            getResources().getStringArray(positions.get(POSITION1)));
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using switch to simplify

```
int selectedArray = 0;
switch(POSITION1) {
case 1:
    selectedArray = R.array.Électron_P;
    break;
case 2:
    selectedArray = R.array.Monstre_P;
    break;
case 3:
    selectedArray = R.array.Neutron_P;
    break;
}

ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this,
        R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice_2,
        getResources().getStringArray(selectedArray));
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but my guess is that this is quite verbose compared to a look-up structure like an array or `Map`.